# How can I create a method to check if gameobject contain specific component/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I'm doing:

```
if (gameObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() == true
    && gameObj.GetComponent<BoxCollider>() == true)
    fontColor = meshRendererColor;
```

But instead adding && many times for each component to create a method that you can get array of components and it will return true if the gameobject contain them.

```
private static bool IsContainComponents(string[] components, GameObject gameObj)
{
    bool contain = false;

    return contain;
}
```

Comment: Return true if it contains all the components stored as string? false if it doesn't contain any one of them?

Comment: Yes as string. Maybe to store it as Component array is better but I think as string is fine.

Comment: @DubiDuboni: My advice is to avoid string unless you absolute need it (User IO, XML, some braindead API that uses strings). It is the 2nd worst data type you can have, being only overshadowed by raw binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to use string for this, use `Type.GetType` to convert the name of the component which is a string to `Type` then use the `GetComponent` overload that take Type as argument. If the component is false, just return `false`.

```
private static bool IsContainComponents(string[] components, GameObject gameObj)
{
    foreach (var cp in components)
    {
        //Convert the component to Type
        Type type = Type.GetType(cp);
        //Get component with this component
        Component component = gameObj.GetComponent(type);
        //If it is null exit the loop then return false
        if (component == null)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This should work with your own components. If using built-in Unity components, you must must prefix it with the namespace `UnityEngine` then the component name followed by comma and the namespace again.

For example, if you're looking for a `Rigidbody` which is a built-in component, that would be `"UnityEngine.Rigidbody, UnityEngine"` **not** `"Rigidbody"`.

or

```
Debug.Log(IsContainComponents(new string[] {"UnityEngine.Rigidbody, UnityEngine" }, gameObject));
```

You can also fix this by just using `Component` instead of `string`.

```
private static bool IsContainComponents(Component[] components, GameObject gameObj)
{
    foreach (var cp in components)
    {
        //Get component with this component
        Component component = gameObj.GetComponent(cp.GetType().Name);
        //If it is null exit the loop then return false
        if (component == null)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) has an overload that takes a `System.Type`.

So your method could be:

```
public static bool HasAllComponents(GameObject gameObject, params System.Type[] types)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
    {
        if (gameObject.GetComponent(types[i]) == null)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note the `params` keyword which lets you call the method without making the array manually: `HasAllComponents(gameObject, typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BoxCollider), etc);`.